# iOS Receipt Validation failing on an MDM device

Tags: validation, mdm, receipt

If you see this post on the apple dev forums, it's because I posted in both places.

I have an app that I'm doing receipt validation via the validateReceipt endpoint (for iOS15) and the new StoreKit2 AppTransaction for iOS16. All is well until...

A user reported that the app keeps telling him that there is no app receipt to validate and wants him to sign in and get a new receipt. Trouble is, his iPad is under device management from Mosyle and he doesn't have the account ID or password to sign in with. Well duh, of course not, that's handled by IT.

My understanding is that the receipt is tied to the user account and the device that the app is on, so if the app is being distributed from a server then the receipt won't match the device, or possibly isn't even part of the distribution. I'm unclear on this, as all I'm getting is an alert about the receipt. I'm adding more code to detect and report on what might be happening inside the app, but in the meanwhile I have to figure out what to do to get rid of the warning prompt.

My questions, after having read volumes of unhelpful information about MDM's, are simple. Is there a way to detect inside the app if the app was installed via an MDM? Can I tell from inside the app if the device is registered in an MDM? And how can I tell that the app is authorized to run on the device if the receipt validation methods aren't, well, valid?

I have tried multiple combinations of search terms yet nowhere can I find out how to detect a valid MDM configuration and thus not look at the receipt. It seems the answer is either that developers aren't checking their receipt or that the solution is so blazingly simple that I'm just not seeing it.